# How can I know what site is generating memory overhead on IIS

Tags: iis, azure-monitoring

I'm monitoring some apps on IIS using [Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/azure/azure-monitor/learn/quick-collect-windows-computer).

All the process running on IIS has the name W3WP, which is OK.
But, how can I know which site is W3WP#6, so I can investigate some anomalies like these memory overheads?

[image: Process Log]